# xcode disassociate IBAction button h file

Tags: xcode, ibaction

Hello all how do I disassociate a button in a h file? I accidentally associated an IBAction button to h files how do I remove the association?

I tried to add a image but it will not let me sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the button and look at the "Connections inspector" for that button (along the right side of the Xcode project window), you'll be able to "X" (i.e. disconnect) the action connection.

When I do it, it should look like this:

[image: Click The X]